# How to add border for Container in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have Container look like below. I want to add border for this Container like text box border please help to add border for the Container.

```
MyContainer13Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
    flex: 1,
    width: 500,
    height: 22,
    activeItem: 0,
    id: 'url',
    initComponent: function() {
        MyContainer13Ui.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try the style config: `style:'border:1px black solid'`

Comment: You're going to use CSS in either case, whether it's through #url {border:...} or by using the style attribute.

Comment: You can use a Panel instead of container.

Answer (score 7):

If you can't just set **border: true** in the configuration, try this:

```
 MyContainer13Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
    flex: 1,
    width: 500,
    height: 22,
    border: 1,
    style: {
       borderColor: 'black',
       borderStyle: 'solid'
    },
    activeItem: 0,
    id: 'url',
    initComponent: function() {
        MyContainer13Ui.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```